# How to sum up numbers in my file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a folder, `my_folder`, which contains over 800 files, `myfile_*` where * is the unique ID for each file. In my file I basically have a variety of repeated fields but the one I am interested in is the `<rating>` field. Lines of this field look like the following: `<rating>n` where n is the rating score. These lines occur every 14th line, starting at line 10 (10 + 14i) and ending when the file ends. It is my job to write a script, `myscript.sh`, to sum up all values of n per file in my folder and then sort from highest to smallest. The output would look as follows

```
myfile_1234 5112
myfile_5214 2134
myfile_6124 1233
...
```

where the number suffixes are the sum of n per file. My files vary in length dramatically from as little as 20  fields to as many as 2500. How would I go about doing this? I figure that I will use some form of `grep` command to find occurences of `<rating>` and then sum up the numbers following the occurences, or maybe could use the fact that the lines occur every 10 + 14i lines, starting at 10. Thanks for your time any suggestions are much appreciated.

**Input File:**

```
<Overall Rating>2.5
<Avg. Price>$155
<URL>

<Author>Jeter5
<Content>I hope we're not disappointed! We enjoyed New Orleans...
<Date>Dec 19, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<rating>4
<Value>-1
<Rooms>3
<Location>5
<Cleanliness>3
<Check in / front desk>5
<Service>5
<Business service>5

<Author>...
repeat fields again...
```

The script must take the folder name as an argument in the command line, such as `./myscript.sh my_folder`

Comment: could you please add a short example of the input file?

Comment: I am not allowed to use the overall rating field, I must calculate it myself.

Comment: So a hotel with 10 ratings of 1 star each time will come out better than a hotel with a single rating of 5 stars?

Comment: I worry about that later, but for now just need to sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
#/bin/bash
dir=$1

grep -P -o '(?<=<rating>).*' $dir/* |awk -F: '{A[$1]+=$2;next}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}'|sort -n -k2
```

Looks like the sort at the end wasn't needed, so you could remove that.

Comment: How would I remove the folder name prefix from my output to give an output similar to the one I showed in my question?

Comment: add `cd $dir` before the grep command, and change `$dir/*` to `*`

Answer (score 2):

you could use `awk` and don't care about the starting line

If I well understood, if you type the following command:

```
grep rating fileName.txt
```

you'll have something like (I've created a sample input file):

```
grep "<rating>" myfile_12345
<rating>7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<rating>1
<rating>2
```

you can use this `awk`

```
awk -F"<rating>" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum+=$2}END{print sum}' myfile_12345
```

ouput:

```
10
```

then you can use it in a `for` loop

```
for file in $(find . -name "myfile_*")
do
  printf "%s $file "
  awk -F"<rating>" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum+=$2}END{printf " %s\t\n", sum}' $file
done
```

output:

```
./myfile_12345  10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
./myfile_17676  19                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
./myfile_9898  24
```

Best Regards

Claudio

Comment: Thanks for your help, my output from your program however is not sorted

Comment: add | sort -n  at the end of awk

Comment: My answer got accepted, but this is more explanatory, so I've upvoted it